# Generating random numbers 1-100

Tags: c#, random, max, average, min

I need to generate random numbers from 1 to 100 and I know how to do that part...

I need to ask user how many numbers he wants to generate(if he says 5  the program needs to generate 5 numbers from 1 to 100). I only now how to make a fixable amount by adding new int's in a list.

I did achieve that before, but then i couldn't make it work, so it would write average of those numbers and min+max value.

Here is my code below:

```
Random k = new Random(); 
//here i added in the same way other variables and put them in a list
int j = k.Next(100);

Console.WriteLine("");
double[] list1 = {j}; 
double povp = list1.Average();
Console.WriteLine(povp);

Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine(list1.Max()); 
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine(list1.Min());

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use the following code to generate N numbers:

```
IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Repeat(1,N).Select(_ => random.Next(100));
```

Comment: `100` is exclusive, while OP probably asked about inclusive `100`. Also, it's a good practice to note lambda parameter as `_`, when you don't use it. So I would write `.Select(_ => random.Next(101))`

Comment: I love the idea of using '_' in this case - having started to learn Haskell. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
// ask user for input
string input = Console.Readline();
int parsed;
// parse to int, needs error checking (will throw exception when input is not a valid int)
int.TryParse(input, out parsed);

Random random = new Random();
List<double> list = new List<double>();

for(int i = 0; i < parsed; parsed++)
{
  list.Add(random.Next(100));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Main()
        {
            const int NUMBERS_FROM = 1;
            const int NUMBERS_TO = 100;

            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Random rnd = new Random();
            List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                int rndNumber = rnd.Next(NUMBERS_FROM, NUMBERS_TO + 1);
                numbers.Add(rndNumber);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Numbers : {0}",string.Join(", ",numbers));
        }
```

this will generate N numbers and add them to a list and then print them to the console. I think this is what you were looking for